# sps 2013 designer workflow get automatically rejected

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow

[image]I've made a 2013 approval workflow in designer.

Whenever someone other than me submits a new list item the first steps of the workflow run (the submitter gets an email notification) but seconds after submission the workflow status goes straight to “Rejected” status and the approval task emails are not sent.

i tried giving write permissions to the task and history lists, but it didn't work.

would appreciate some help
Shira

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your workflow?

Comment: hi,the workflow is in Hebrew, so i'm not sure it will do much help.

Comment: Hello its caused by the App Step and then you publish under you. Probably you need impersonation step instead of App Step and after editing WF, publish it under Site Collection Administrator.

Comment: thank you for your answer. i tried it with and without the app step. in 2013 workflow, the app step supposed to replace the  impersonation step that was in 2010. i am a site collection admin, so how do i publish it under Site Collection Administrator?